# Python send string of settings in one message over MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm looking into sending one message over MQTT through Python to a subscriber who will perform an action for me.

This message will overall contain several variables and values and other settings (instructions) on how to perform the action.

I'm not quite sure how to formulate the message so that it's easier to subtract it from the subscriber's end and categorize/use the instructions.

I would be grateful if people could share some insight in and how to approach this.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Good question! I've looked at sending the information through a string, and cutting/organizing what i need. Sadly though because the order of string changes, this becomes quite complex. I was just now looking at JSON, but as I have never worked with this before it looks quite complex and I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: JSON would be my choice, but I've not used it with Python (apart from the built in pretty printer)